# glGenVertexArrays incredibly slow

Tags: c++, opengl, vao

I am currently writing a game with opengl, that has to create vertex arrays while running.

The problem is, each time the program calls 'glGenVertexArrays', not at initialization, the call makes it freeze, (10 to 100 ms).

To solve this, i made the game create empty VAOs at initialization, and fill them after, but now the first time those empty VAOs get bound, the same weird freeze occur.

Is this the wrong way to create VAOs during the game?

Or perhaps is this issue just on my machine (ndivia geforce940mx)?

The simple code i use in my loop to create a vao (which is called ~ 1 time per frame):

```
float cl = Timer::clock();

int vao_id;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao_id);

cl = Timer::clock()-cl;
printf("%f\n", cl);
// this weirdly gives 10 - 100 ms
```

Comment: 'Is this the wrong way to create VAOs during the game?' Can we see your code please?

Comment: The fact that you see some delay on a GL command on the CPU does **not** imply that this GL command is actually triggering the delay. The GPU works asynchronous, and the nvidia driver works asynchronous on the CPU in separate threads. I t is more likely that the rest of your GL code triggers some sort of synchronization.

Comment: "has to create vertex arrays while running" -- I bet they all have the same format (set of attributes, instancing, etc...). If so you should have only one VAO per format and swap the buffers, or the data in the buffers, potentially packing all those meshes into a single buffer.

Comment: There is rarely any good reason to create VAOs in your update/render loop. `printf` will likely take longer than anything else in your sample, and the lack of a real example makes any answer or comment you'll find here pure conjecture.

Comment: I didnt make myself clear.
I'm creating a Minecraft clone, and manage the terrain generation and mesh creation in a second thread. However, i must create the vao and fill the vbos in the main thread, which doesn't seems to take long since the biggest part is done in another thread. The problem is : it does take very long, because the glGenVertexArrays takes tenths of milliseconds. Thus, i partially solved the issue by creating more than one mesh in a frame (it just freezes one time 10ms insted of 10 times 10ms) because weirdly, only the first call takes time, the others weirdly are instants

Comment: @FredPainDemi: "i must create the vao" -- there's your problem. **You don't need to create a VAO** each time you create a mesh. You only need to update the buffers. If the mesh is big then you can avoid the overhead of the driver copying the data by memory-mapping your buffer. See [buffer streaming](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming).